# Manage Firebase from mobile device

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Does anyone know of any way to manage Firebase Firestore from a smartphone?
Firebase Console doesn’t work from the mobile browser. Are there any apps for that?

Comment: Currently nothing official yet from Google or Firebase Team

Comment: If you can add more details about  the browser that you are trying to access the console from?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour ios safari

Comment: Did you try Chrome Browser .. I think it is will be Great as All of Them Google Products?

Comment: I agree with @KevinM.Mansour, try different browser and it should work on Chrome Browser.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour i just checked chrome, it doesnt work there either. You cant navigate past the document list column to see the actual document

Comment: So I am sorry .. I did not help you .. But I wanted to help .. I preferred Chrome Browser (Beacause Chrome & Firebase Google Products) .. I usually open Firebase Console from Chrome on Android 10 .. And it is working well .. I hope Google create Android App for Firebase Console as well like Google Ads .. Google Cloud Platform .. I will submit an answer as There is no way for That

Comment: I have my iPhone 11 in front of me and, using Safari, I am logged into the console. In the Realtime Database section I can add and remove nodes and review data. It doesn't work perfectly (the UI needs work) but it is somewhat usable. It's unclear what isn't working for you.

Comment: On my iphone 8 You cant navigate past the document list column to see the actual document

Comment: Well, in Cloud Firestore, it's working on my iPhone in Safari (not well, but it works) and I can tap a collection on the left to see the documents and then tap a document to see it's fields. Try landscape mode on your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

For now there is no Official App from Google or Firebase Team ..
And it is likely the site have small problems on iOS Safari Browser .. So there is no answer for now .. I hope Google or Firebase Team Create App for the site like Google Ads or Google Cloud Platform